# Buefy carousel template slot indicator showing broken image

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, buefy, vuejs3

Hi i am newbie in buefy and vuejs i have different url in my json array that need to be display in buefy carousel however whenever im using the template slot="indicators" the image is showing broken image. the  is already showing the image but in template slot="indicators" is showing broken image.
Can someone help me? Thank you

Here is the code:

```html
<b-carousel :indicator-inside="false">
    <b-carousel-item v-for="(itemss,i) in imgsplit" v-bind:prop="itemss" v-bind:key="i">
        <span class="image">
            <img v-bind:src="getImgUrl(imgsplit[i])" />
        </span>
    </b-carousel-item>

    <template slot="indicators" slot-scope="props">
        <span class="al image">
            <img :src="props.i" :title="props.i" />
        </span>
    </template>
</b-carousel>
```

Method

```js
    // ...

    getImgUrl(value) {
      return value
    },

    // ...
```

sample of JSON array

```js
[
    'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountain-landscape-lake-range-large-260nw-1017466240.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/da/1b/73/da1b7357ff266888dd43b84e9162731b.jpg',
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on their [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Matt-Stevens/pen/Pozpoze):

```html
<div id="app" class="container">
    
    <b-carousel :indicator-inside="false">
        <b-carousel-item v-for="(item, i) in images" :key="i">
            <span class="image">
              <img :src="getImgUrl(i)">
            </span>
        </b-carousel-item>

        <template slot="indicators" slot-scope="props">
            <span class="al image">
                <img :src="getImgUrl(props.i)" :title="props.i">
            </span>
        </template>
    </b-carousel>

</div>
```

```js
const example = {
  data: ({
    images: [
      'https://image-url/one.jpg',
      'https://image-url/two.jpg',
      'https://image-url/three.jpg',
    ],
  }),
  
  methods: {
    getImgUrl(value) {
      return this.images[value];
    }
  }
};

const app = new Vue(example);
app.$mount("#app");
```